# How to set if clause in twig?

Tags: php, twig

I have these two functions:

```
function is_expired($object) {
              if (new DateTime('NOW') > $object) {
                  return true;
              } else {
                  return false;
              }
}

function is_not_started($object) {
              if (new DateTime('NOW') < $object) {
                  return false;
              } else {
                  return true;
              }
}
```

$object is Datetime object fetched from db. and I also registered functions as twig filter.

For a voting system I have two fields start_date and expiry_date, I want to see if this is not expired but already started.

In twig I have:

```
{% if (category.endVote|is_expired == false) or (category.startVote|is_not_started == true) %}
<td><a href="voting.php?id={{ category.id }}">{{ category.categoryName|e }}</a></td>
{% else %}
<td>{{ category.categoryName|e }}</td>
{% endif %}
```

I mean I want to see categoryName as link only if this is started and is NOT expired. but it doesn't work as expected. What wrong I did in my if clause?

Comment: Notice the word you use in your description: "if this is started **and** is NOT expired" and the one in your code: `if (...)` **or** `(...)`. You've basically described the solution yourself :)

Comment: actually I tried that too, but I guess something still wrong in functions, can you please look at them and help?

Comment: Ah, yes, the "inverted" logic... "started" equals to `is_not_started` giving `false`, not `true`.

Comment: A tip: don't write functions that handle "negative" cases. Make a function `is_started`, then negate it inside logical expressions. When you name it negatively, to get a positive version, you have to negate the negation... so you end up with an expression that reads as "if not is not started...", which isn't really natural. It's much cleaner to just have "if is started" and "if not is started".

Comment: Just a small note. Renaming your function `is_not_started` to `is_started` makes your code easier to understand. Having a double negative like `is_not_started` returning false can easily become hard to wrap your head around.

Comment: Why don't you just combine them in a filter `is_active`? Or even better add a method `isActive()` in your object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I would recommend.

```
function can_vote($object) {
    $now = new \DateTime('now');
    return $object->getEndVote() < $now && $object->getStartVote() > $now;
}

{% if category|can_vote is same as(true) %}
    <td><a href="voting.php?id={{ category.id }}">{{ category.categoryName|e }}</a></td>
{% else %}
    <td>{{ category.categoryName|e }}</td>
{% endif %}
```

Instead of two separate functions, merge these into one and pass in the entire category object. Also in the twig part, I recommend to use the more stricter equation instead of "==" the one in my code equates to "===".
Make note of the getEndVote() and getStartVote() getter methods, if You use public properties, change those to reflect the correct names.

If you wish to use two separate methods in the end it is not difficult to extract that functionality but i think this is a better solution.